# ASP.NET: Moving ViewState to bottom of page

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, webforms

What are the latest and greatest ways to move ViewState to **bottom of the page**

Can this be done in a **IHttpHandler** that can be specified in the **web.config** to intercept requests to "*.aspx"?

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="MyApp.OptimizedPageHandler" />
<httpHandlers>
```

Other options is that this could be done in a **IHttpModule**, but that is *not as performant*, as it will intercept all requests.

Also it could be done in an a class deriving from the **Page** or **MasterPage**-class, but this is *not as modular*.

Are there any **performance penalties** to this?

Comment: Can I ask why you'd want to move it to the bottom of the page?  I doubt anyone cares how sexy your rendered HTML looks :)

Comment: @Polaris878, that I agree with (+1), but, for pages with humongous viewstate, it would make them easier on the eye when viewing source/debugging :)

Comment: The search crawlers care.

Comment: Like @IrishCieftain says, it's about SEO.

Comment: How does the view state data positioning affect SEO (I'm not debating, I'm asking, really)?

Comment: its is good to not have viewstate on the first part of your page, because after first part load, you can flush it and show something before the next part come. This way you make user experience a lot of better.

Comment: The bots only take X amount of bytes from pages, so if that is Viewstate you miss out on indexed real content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After conducting some research I put together [this blog-post](http://www.sebnilsson.com/blog/2010/3/30/aspnet-webforms-seo-moving-view-state-to-bottom-of-the-form.html).

I solved the issue by creating a **HttpModule** and applying a **Response Filter**, which **modifies the output** of the page and moves the ViewState to the bottom of the form.

```
public class ViewStateSeoHttpModule : IHttpModule {
    public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(BeginRequest);
    }

    private void BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        HttpApplication application = sender as HttpApplication;

        bool isAspNetPageRequest = GetIsAspNetPageRequest(application);
        if(isAspNetPageRequest) {
            application.Context.Response.Filter =
                new ViewStateSeoFilter(application.Context.Response.Filter);
        }
    }

    private bool GetIsAspNetPageRequest(HttpApplication application) {
        bool isAspNetPageRequest = application.Context.Handler is System.Web.UI.Page;
        return isAspNetPageRequest;
    }
    // [...]
```

Comment: that is pretty optimistic... what about extensionless urls or if you're using something else than aspx?

No, you should instead look at whether your current handler is a System.Web.UI.Page or not.

bool isAspNetPageRequest = application.Context.Handler is System.Web.UI.Page;

Answer (score 2):

You can control how and where ViewState data is loaded and saved by creating a custom implementation of the `PageStatePersister` class.  Then create a base class for all your `ASPX` pages and override the `PageStatePersister` method to return your custom implementation.  This can then tap into whichever page events you want to store the viewstate per your requirements.

I question whether or not it's worthwhile though.  Are you storing a ton of data int he `ViewState` unnecessarily?  Maybe you can get more benefit easier by just using `ViewState` less or turning it off for some controls as opposed to just moving it to a different place within the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the Page class gives you the most control over page rendering. If you want to move ViewState to the bottom of a given page, use your custom base class for that page. If you don't need to, use the Page class.

The only performance risk when deriving from the Page class is in your implementation of overridden methods. Unless you're doing something particularly inefficient, there should not be any perceptible performance hit.