# ASP.NET and HTML pages - some advice needed from Search Engine perspective

Tags: asp.net, html, seo

I have a bunch of aspx (asp.net) and html pages. The site is active past 2 years and gets decent traffic. Now all this while, I have not taken care of SEO. So my pages do not have meta tags, description or H1, H2 and so on.

Now I plan to add them to my pages and do this the right way. My question in any way will this **negatively impact SEO, like any penalty**. Also when Google and other search engines reindex the pages, are there chances they will notice it and rank the pages higher?

Infact every page content is full of inline JS and CSS, which I know is wrong. I plan to remove them to an external file. The actual content is also way below.

Do you know of any other similar tips for ASP.NET 4.0 or HTML sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google ignores keyword meta tags.
[reference](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html)

So, no penalty there.  There are some benefits to using some of the other tags.

And please, if you're using h1 and h2 tags do it because it looks better to a person, not because you've decided a search engine might like it.

The best SEO is an excellent page that people actually want to come to.  You'll get tons of good incoming links.

Comment: From an SEO perspective, what is the bare minimum and correct structure a Page must have. I know good content is one, but from a Search Engine perspective, how can i maximize my chances that my page is ranked well. Also you

Comment: I would say the bare minimum is a well formed html document.  You can use the w3c validator if you want to be sure. http://validator.w3.org/  Also check out Google's SEO starter guide http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/11/googles-seo-starter-guide.html

Comment: Oooh the Google Starter guide is what i wanted. thanks champion!

Comment: The new version (2010) of Google SEO Starter Guide is here: http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

For SEO, [content is king](http://www.google.com/search?q=seo+content+is+king&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a).

Answer (score 0):

i worked for one of the biggest (think it was in the top 10) websites (in from of revenue and visits) ever built on a .net only plattform as an SEO.

the best tip i ever had for the .net developers is:

- do not use postbacks for navigation, use links (yeah, simple GET request links)

i'm not sure why postbacks are (or were) so damn popular with .net devs, but they were. and it killed their performance in goolgle (gooogelbot does not do postbacks).

Answer (score 0):

May not apply to you but....Spiders read HTML pages from the top down and have a limit as to how much text they will parse before quitting. Moving Viewstate to the bottom will prevent the spider from only reading bloated viewstate (then quitting due to character limit) and not ever getting to your real content.

[ASP.NET: Moving ViewState to bottom of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380124/asp-net-moving-viewstate-to-bottom-of-page)